# The definition of the Lovász $\vartheta$ function

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

The definition of $\vartheta$ is on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_number).

I can't understand how this function is well defined when we could very well have a vector $c$ that is orthogonal to some $u_i$. Is it implied that the minimum is over all vectors $c$ with $c$ not orthogonal to every $u_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that we treat $\frac1{(c^{\mathsf T} u_i)^2}$ as being equal to $+\infty$ if $c^{\mathsf T} u_i = 0$. Thus, for a particular orthonormal representation $U$ and vector $c$, 
$$
    \max_{i \in V} \frac1{(c^{\mathsf T} u_i)^2}
$$
will be $+\infty$ if $c$ is orthogonal to some $u_i$, and finite otherwise.

However, we minimize over both $U$ and $c$, and we can always choose a $c$ which is not orthogonal to any $u_i$, so we'll always get a finite value for $\vartheta(G)$.